# R - Error: is.character(location) is not TRUE

Tags: r, google-maps, csv, geocoding

I am new to R. I found a script online which is used to batch geocode a list of addresses.

http://www.storybench.org/geocode-csv-addresses-r/

However I keep getting this error message 'Error: is.character(location) is not TRUE'...anyone have any ideas on how to reslove the issue??

```
# Geocoding script for large list of addresses. 
# Finbar Gillen 25/07/2018
#load up the ggmap library
install.packages('ggmap')
library(ggmap)
# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude 
of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = 
"latlona", source = "google")
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working 
directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After # Print("Working...")
it shall be name of column of your inputfile/dataframe and not 'addresses'
result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = 
"latlona", source = "google")

Comment: Hi Shama, thanks! I didn't have a capital letter for the start of the column name. The code is interrupted when an address can’t be coded. Do you know how i could modify the code so it shows “not found” and proceeds onto the next address?